# How to enforce https for all directories except a few inside the parent directory for adon domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, https

I have a public_html which i want to have https enforced but not include some directories inside this folder since those folders are parent directories that hold files for other domains which don't have SSL installed on them.

I used this to enforce https for the entire public_html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But i wanted to exclude some directories and the following is not working.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^site2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Thanks.

Comment: `REQUEST_URI` always begins with a leading slash: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site2 [NC]` which means `if uri begins with site2...`

Comment: Just to add to previous comment, you're not excluding site2, you're conditioning site2 to be on HTTPS, whereas every other uri would have HTTPS off.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is to base your rule on the Domain(s) the request is for e.g.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} yourSecure.domain  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} yourOtherSecure.domain  [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```